# Get all links requested by a website page from Curl or any library using PHP

Tags: php, curl, request

Like Google Chrome and Firefox browser can show all the links requested by a loaded website page, I want to know if is it possible to get all the links requested by a website page using PHP.

So if a web browser and other applications can do it, I believe PHP can do it too.

**I am not talking about getting the links written from a website page. Like, When a page loaded, it can make request to other sites (connect to Facebook or Twitter like o share buttons, load an audio or image file...). I want to see these links that was requested.**

Comment: [DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName('a')](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php)?

Comment: I already said. I don't want to find out the links on a page. I want the links that a page requested. Like, When a page loaded, it can make request to other sites. I want to see this links that was requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You are talking about Javascript calls made by the target site after initial page render of the target site.**

- **cURL** and **PHP** have no javascript parser as such, if under the "links" you are referring a content loaded by `javascript/ajax` calls after initial page load. That dynamically loaded content is not available with cURL request, is it then done with PHP `cURL` or not.

I suggest you try to learn about **web crawlers** and mocking **web browsers** which may provide you the way to accomplish what you are trying to do.

**You may want to check out following related question:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/1535621/1318830

Comment: Not only content loaded by Ajax or Ajax calls. But, also when the browser load an image, a song file (`audio.play()`). I will take this answer under consideration. Because you just clear me about, faking a web browser(controlling a web page) using a server side language. I will explore Google to find out more and fit it to get to my goal.